# Mvc OnException when Viewname and Action name is different

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, exception

I know that there are some types of handling exception on MVC. I choosed creating a base controller and overriding the OnException method. Everything is fine but in one of my controllers i have an post action name different from the view name like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Kaydet(PersonelModel model)
    {
        var personel = new Personel();
        SimpleMapper.PropertyMap(model,personel);
        _personelService.Ekle(personel);

        model.Id = personel.Id;
        model.UyariBilgisi.BildirimTipi=BildirimTipi.Bilgi;
        model.UyariBilgisi.UyariMetni = "Kayıt başarıyla eklendi.";
        return View("PersonelDetay", model);
    }
```

the view name is PersonelDetay.
Here is my OnException Method

```
 protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

        if (exception is NotificationException)
        {

            ViewModelBase viewModelBase = new ViewModelBase()
            {
                UyariBilgisi = new UyariBilgisi() { UyariMetni = exception.Message, BildirimTipi = BildirimTipi.Uyari }
            };

            filterContext.Result = View(viewModelBase);

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

When the Kaydet method gets an notification exception OnException method works and tries to return "Kaydet" view but there is no view named "Kaydet"

To solve this problem i nedd the view name in OnException event. How can i get viewname? or do i thinking wrong? is there a better way a best practice ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I would probably return a error specific view from `OnException`. If you found an approach where the same view was returned in both cases, then you would have a situation where, in the first example, you will pass a `PersonelModel` instance into the view and in the second example you will pass a `ViewModelBase` instance into the view. Your view would then have to written in a way that could handle these two different types of models.

Comment: I am just catching validation exception in on exception event and want to show a notification in the same view. my Layout.cshtml has model ViewModelBase and show a notification according to coming message

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

In your controller add the member variable `Dictionary<string, string> _viewNames` and then within your constructor initialize the collection using an action name as the key and the name of the view as the value:

```
_viewNames = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{
    { "Kaydet", "PersonelDetay" }
}
```

Then create a method that will return a view name for the current action:

```
private string GetViewName() 
{
    return _viewNames[this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()];
}
```

Change the `return` statement in the action to:

```
return View(GetViewName(), model)
```

and in `OnException` replace `filterContext.Result` with:

```
filterContext.Result = View(GetViewName(), viewModelBase);
```

Now this isn't ideal for a number of reasons, e.g. actions returning different views, action name changes have to be reflected when initializing the collection, etc, etc, but it may be useful for your current situation.

If there was a way to register different view names with MVC rather than pass them into the `View` method, then you could have `OnException` simply call `View(viewModelBase)` and have it use your custom named view, from any method, based on the action currently being executed.